# Haskell - Mixed stateful computations

Tags: haskell, monads, state-monad

Given the following structure:

```
data Computation a = Pure (CState -> (a, CState))
                   | Action (CState -> IO (a, CState))
```

(CState is some structure used for keeping a state, but is not of much interest now.)
Now I want to make it an instance of Monad, which is basically just a state monad and would be easily implemented with StateT. The only addition it has, is that I want to keep track, whether the resulting Computation is a Pure on or an Action and I want to be able to check whether a Computation contains any `Action`s, before executing an `Action`(so the IO in the `Action` doesn't get executed).

It should be also noted, that it doesn't really matter that `Computation` has two constructors. I just started implementing this with these constructors.

The rules of determining whether `a >> b` is Pure is simple:
`a >> b` is `Pure` if `a` and `b` are both `Pure`, otherwise it's an action.

Now I started implementing the Monad instance:

```
instance Monad Computation where
    return x = Pure $ \s -> (x, s)
    (Action c) >>= f = Action . runStateT $
                         (StateT $ unpackAction oldComp) >>= (StateT . unpackAction . f)
    p@(Pure c) >>= f
      | givesPure f = Pure . runState $
                        state oldF >>= (state . unpackPure . f)
      | otherwise = liftComp p >>= f -- Just lift the first argument and recurse, to make an action

-- Helper functions used above:
unpackAction :: Computation a -> (CState -> IO (a, CState))
unpackAction (Pure c) = return . c 
unpackAction (Action c) = c

-- Make an Action out of a Pure
liftComp :: Computation a -> Computation a
liftComp (Pure c) = Action $ return . c
liftComp a@(Action _) = a
```

So the only missing part is the `givesPure`function and I'm not sure if it's even possible to implement it. I once had an implementation like this:

```
givesPure :: (a -> Computation b) -> Bool
givesPure f = isPure $ f undefined -- I actually used error with a custom message instead of undefined, but that shouldn't matter

isPure :: Computation a -> Bool
isPure (Pure _) = True
isPure (Action _) = False
```

This works, but makes the assumption that the function that I'm binding to, alway returns a Computation with the same purity, regardless of what its input is. This assumption appeared reasonably to me, since the purity of a Computation should be clearly stated and not depend on some calculations, until I noticed that a function in the following form dosn't work with this assumption:

```
baz :: Int -> Computation b
baz x = if x > 5 
        then foo
        else bar
-- foo and bar both have the type Computation b
```

So it seems to me, like it's impossible to do this, since I need the current state to apply the first Computation to, to get a proper input for the function to get the second Computation and test whether it's pure.

Does anyone see a solution to this or has a proof that it isn't possible?

Comment: It's actually the same as `Comp`, I just got mixed up, because I use `Computation`in the real code but wanted to make it shorter here, but ended up writing it full most of the time. I edited the answer to make it `Computation`everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a GADT:

```
data Pure
data Action

data Computation t a where
   Pure :: (CState -> (a, CState))      -> Computation t a
   Action :: (CState -> IO (a, CState)) -> Computation Action a
```

The idea is that a value  `x :: Computation Action a` can do IO (but could also be pure), while a value `y :: Computation Pure a` can not do IO.

For instance,

```
liftComp :: Computation t a -> Computation Action a
liftComp (Pure c) = Pure c
liftComp x@(Action c) = x
```

Comment: In what way is that different (and more important how does it help) from what I already have?

Comment: @Kritzefitz You have a type `Computation Pure a` which guarantees there's a `Pure` inside, not an `Action`.

Comment: But then I'm not able to do `(x :: Computation Pure a) >>= (y :: a -> Computation Action b)` (since they have different types), which is an important thing to do.

Comment: True, but if `x` is polymorphic `x :: forall t. Computation t a`, then is also IO-free, nd can be used `x >>= (y :: a -> Computation Action b)`. Basically the trick is that pure things are polymorphic (they are pure, but they are also not), while impure are only monomprohic Actions.

Comment: I'm not really into `forall` and what it means. How would I make `t` polymorphic?

Comment: Defining `x = Pure ...` would make it polymorphic, Also `x1 >> x2` is poly is `x1,x2` are both poly; if instead one is poly and the other is mono, then `x1 >> x2` is mono since the poly gets instantiatied.

Comment: But I still don't get what my Monad instance would look like.

Answer (score 2):

You have encountered the fact that monadic computations aren't suitable for static analysis, because the effects (in your case, the presence of effects) depend on values obtained during the computation itself. You can't predict them without running the computation.

As you go from `Applicative` to `Arrow` to `Monad`, you gain in "power" (you can express more computations) but lose in amenability to static analysis.

For `Applicative`s, there's a ready-made [`Lift`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.2.0/docs/Control-Applicative-Lift.html#t:Lift) datatype that adds a pure computation to an already existing applicative. But it doesn't have a `Monad` instance.